# How to create href link to function

Tags: javascript

I want to create link that send to function:

```
    tdLink2.innerText="Delete";
    tdLink2.href="javascript:deleteDepartment(id)"
```

but the "id" parameter was not sent.
How can I insert the parameter?

Comment: Where is that `id` coming from? If you want to get the ID from the element itself, then use `this.id`. In one way or another, it's probably always a better idea to use event listeners in JS over inline JS.

Comment: don't use an anchor tag with an href to just trigger javascript. Links are for navigating to other pages. Use a button instead, and add a `click` event handler function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `id` is already a defined variable then you can do like this:

```js
tdLink2.href=`javascript:deleteDepartment(${id})`
```

You can do this if it is of type string.

Otherwise you can go for this:

```js
function f(){
  deleteDepartment(id)
}
tdLink2.href='javascript:f()'
```

Comment: The first one works fine if id is string otherwise second is better incase of objects or arrays

Comment: why comment your own answer, you can edit the answer

Comment: Not a great idea to have a delete in a href. If you have a bot that follows javascript robots you will delete all departments from one visit

Comment: You answer is in principle identical to what I already posted.

Comment: @mplungjan It uses template strings, superior to the GWBASIC string concat ;-)

Comment: EXCEPT you forgot to quote the ID, so you will fail if ID is not a number

Answer (score 2):

ID is not parsed in your string

EITHER (Don't forget the extra quotes if ID is a string

```
tdLink2.href="javascript:deleteDepartment('"+id+"')"
```

alternative with template literals

```
tdLink2.href=`javascript:deleteDepartment('${id}')`;
```

I would personally keep DELETE far away from a href

This is better

```
tdLink2.href="#"
tdLink2.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); /stop the link
  deleteDepartment(id); // id is some global variable
})
```

EVEN better is to do

```
tdLink2.href="#";
td.dataset.id = id; // assign to a data attribute
tdLink2.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // stop the link
  deleteDepartment(this.dataset.id); // pass the data attribute
})
```

Comment: how would you implement a button with the function to delete a Department in the database on the server to prevent these javascript robots to delete your whole database. Add a user login check with a valid role?

Comment: Or just use my third version and have deleteDepartment Ajax to the server

Answer (score -2):

Just assign function result to property

```
tdLink2.href = deleteDepartment(id);
```

Comment: That is VERY bad idea - that will delete the ID immediately you assign and set the href to whatever deleteDepartment returns

Comment: @mplungjan or `deleteDepartment(id)` generates an url that will delete the department, the question is ambiguous.

Comment: The question is completely unambiguous. Also OP likely would not know enough JS to return a function from a function

Comment: @mplungjan `deleteDepartment(id)` can generate a string like `/delete/department/123`

Comment: Yes it could. Bet you a lot that it doesn’t

Comment: @mplungjan unless the OP shows the code for `deleteDepartment` we have to assume and ask, some Web Frameworks have URL generating functions that use the URL dispatch list, and this could be part of a template and he is using the function incorrect

Comment: @mplungjan it is `Naga`'s answer that is accepted

Comment: Now it is. First mine. I assume OP liked the template literals better